# CSS animations slow down desktop browsers but not mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm working on a little project to demo some of the possibilities with variable fonts. You can see the totally unfinished product here: https://curtismann.org/variablefonts/. The gist of the problem is that I have 100 elements being animated (Demo 2), all with the same animation, each with a different delay. The animation looks something like this...

```
@keyframes wave{
  0%{ font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "ital" 2; color: #5c5c5c }
  25%{ font-variation-settings: "wght" 900, "ital" 0; color: #ff1e3c }
  50%{ font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "ital" 2; color: #5c5c5c }
  75%{ font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "ital" 2; color: #ffffff }
  100%{ font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "ital" 2; color: #5c5c5c }
}
```

... and I assign the animation to each element via JS.

```
div.style.animation = "wave 3s " + delay + "s linear infinite";
```

The animations start out buttery smooth for me (on desktop), but after a few iterations they slow down and the page becomes laggy and unresponsive. What is confusing me is that on my phone (both Chrome and Safari), it works without a hiccup.

Comment: For me Chrome is very laggy while Firefox is doing the animation rather smoothly. Even Edge makes it much better than Chrome

Comment: Same. Any idea why? Do you suspect there is a solution or is this the result of just pushing Chrome too far with animations and variable fonts?

Comment: This is new feature so it just needs time for all browser to implement it correctly

Comment: Try maybe with different font

Comment: Different variable font didn't make a difference. I'll stay on the lookout for a solution, but at the moment it works smooth on desktop if I use a 5x5 grid. I'm just perplexed as to why it works well on mobile but not desktop, you'd think it'd be the other way around! Thanks for trying to help.